# Angular set height of table rows on Razor cshtml

Tags: html, css, angularjs, razor, styles

I want to set height of a table row, but when I set the height doesn't respect the defined height and takes different heights and then makes use of the functionality of the style of:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

What I want is to set the height of the table rows to 100px and then, if the text doesn't fit in the cell, show three points to imply that there is more text I think I can do this with the style of the ellipsis...

The summary column is where I don't know how to do what I want:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead config="con" array="list.students" class="table-header"></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="student in list.students">
            <td class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{student.id}}</td>
            <td class="col-md-1 hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{student.Name}}</td>
            <td class="col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{student.Class}}</td>
            <td class="col-md- col-sm-10 col-xs-10" style="padding-left: 10px !important; padding-right: 10px !important;">{{student.Summary}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Might try to change your typo of 'styles' to 'style'

Comment: sorry, I wrote this to simplify my code, but I don't have the typo in the code that I'm running